# Handle SVG sprite file with flutter_svg

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have SVG file on server side named sprite-icons.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 826800 826800">
        <path fill="#222222" d="M201379 197582l31452 0 0 432178 -31452 0 0 -432178zm122701 72034l33469 0 0 282159 -33469 0 0 -282159zm138450 74734l31666 0 0 135933 -31666 0 0 -135933zm131388 -147310l31503 0 0 432178 -31503 0 0 -432178z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 826800 826800">
        <path fill="#aaaaaa" d="M201379 197582l31452 0 0 432178 -31452 0 0 -432178zm122701 72034l33469 0 0 282159 -33469 0 0 -282159zm138450 74734l31666 0 0 135933 -31666 0 0 -135933zm131388 -147310l31503 0 0 432178 -31503 0 0 -432178z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I have url to get it, but when I try do it with [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) this way:

```dart
SvgPicture.network('https://some-domain.com/img/sprite-icons.svg') 
// or 
SvgPicture.network('https://some-domain.com/img/sprite-icons.svg#icon-1')
```

I'm getting an error:

```
StateError (Bad state: SVG did not specify dimensions

The SVG library looks for a `viewBox` or `width` and `height` attribute to determine the viewport boundary of the SVG.  Note that these attributes, as with all SVG attributes, are case sensitive.
```

Is it possible to get such SVG sprite file and render included svgs (icon-1 and icon-2) with flutter_svg? Or any other way? Thanks.

Comment: your svg is broken: view box is 100x100 but the numbers in `d=...` are far bigger like `d="M201379 197582...` are you sure it contains any valid paths?

Comment: @pskink you are right, thank you. I just updated my question with actual viewBox values.